# Is there a way to allow my Subsite to inherit the same Master page from its parent site collection

Tags: development, master-page, site-collection, sub-site

I have a site collection of type Team site, where i did some customization for the `seatle.master` master page using SharePoint designer 2013.

Then i have created a sub-site under the  site collection,, but i have noticed that the master page customization did not apply to the sub site,, so can anyone advice how i can force any sub site to inherit  the same Master page from its parent site collection?

Comment: check this http://www.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2013/7/22/sharepoint-branding-team-sites,-inherit-theme-and-master-page-on-office-365

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is:

- Enable the Publishing feature at site collection
- now browse this page sitecolelction/_layouts/15ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx
- Now you can change the master page for all subsite.[image]

Comment: what if the user create a new sub site ? will it inherit the parent master page ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone who comes across this question.

When I tried

> sitecolelction/_layouts/15ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

from the previous post, I received an error. I discovered there was a typo. "/" missing after 15.

Please use the following to get to the Site Master Page Settings page.

> sitecollection/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx